# Making listview sharedPreference aware

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I have a listview that is populated by a  of my custom classes.

What i'm unsure of the best way to do, is how to make the relationship between the preferences as set by sharedPreferences, and the Listview.

Ideally i thought about adding a "showMe" type member to the class and then in the custom adapter for the listview, I could simply check that flag before i let the adapter add it.
But the problem is, where should I set this flag once the preferences are set ? I know I have onSharedPreferenceChanged() in the SettingsActivity, but how do I reference the List to get at my customer class flag from within the SettingsActivity ?

Is that even the best and most efficient way to do it ?

I also thought about doing it in the onResume of the MainActivity - since it is called when you go back from the SettingsActivity, and atleast in the MainActivity I have access to the List.  But i'm just not sure if that logic is correct because I tried it, and for some reason the list object is not accessible onResume (app crashes).

So I'm after the best practice on how to make my listview aware of preference changes, so that it refreshes itself based on whether each item should be shown or not.

Comment: Hey makapaka, does this solve your problem ? If yes you can upvote the answer too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried localbroadcasting, inside onSharedPreferenceChanged()?

Add a receiver in the activity, so that when ever preferences are changed, pass that data via an intent and receive that in the broadcast receiver and refresh the list.

In your activity:

```
   private BroadcastReceiver statusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
   {
     public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
        {
          //get data from intent
         //use intent.getExtras().get(name);
        };
   };
```

Register the intent in onResume() of the activity as:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                         .registerReceiver(statusReceiver,
                                           new IntentFilter("updateList"));
```

And onPause() remove the listener, so you make sure that when activity is in background, the listener is unregistered.

```
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                         .unregisterReceiver(statusReceiver);
```

And from onSharedPreferenceChanged();

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("updateList");
 intent.putExtra(name, value)
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```